# What is "python -d" for?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I thought it is for activating debug mode which prints all [logging.debug()](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html) messages. But apparently that doesn't happen. [The documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-d) simply says:

> Turn on parser debugging output (for wizards only, depending on compilation options). 
>   See also PYTHONDEBUG.

Which doesn't explain anything in my eyes. Can somebody give a more verbose explanation and verify that there is really no default CPython Argument that activates debug logging?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Parser/parser.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5e98c4e9c909/Parser/parser.c):

```
#ifdef Py_DEBUG
extern int Py_DebugFlag;
#define D(x) if (!Py_DebugFlag); else x
#else
#define D(x)
#endif
```

This `D` macro is used with `printf()` to print debugging messages when the debug flag is supplied and the interpreter is compiled with in debug mode. The debugging messages are intended for the developers of Python, people who work *on* Python itself (not to be confused with Python programmers, who are people who *use* Python). I've gone through the Python manual page and none of them activate the `logging` debug mode. However, one can use the `-i` flag in conjunction with the `-c` to achieve the same affect:

```
python -i -c "import logging;logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)"
```

Comment: Yes, that's also the best I came up with. It works but it is not as beautiful as I would have wished for.

Answer (score 3):

The `-d` option enables the python parser debugging flags. Unless you're hacking the Python interpreter and changing how it parses Python code, you're unlikely to ever need that option.

The logging infrastructure is a standard library module, not a builtin feature of the interpreter. It doesn't make much sense to have an interpreter flag that changes such a localized feature of a module.

Also, consider how logging level depends on the logging logger and handler you're using. You can set different levels for different loggers and handlers, for different parts of your application. For instance, when you want all DEBUG lines from anyone to appear in console, but INFO and above from a lib should be logged to a common file, and WARNING and ERROR to be logged to specific files for easier monitoring. You can set a global handler for DEBUG that logs to console, and other handlers that log the different levels to separate files.

Comment: Yes, from the logging framework developer's point of view your argument makes sense. But because logging and printing debug info is a default task, I think no additional code should be necessary in case I am just debugging a simple script. Therefore adding a sane default logger/handler combination and adding it as an interpreter option would make sense from the usability point of view, at least in my eyes.

Comment: Debugging with logging messages is something I call print-driven-development. You should debug using pdb to inspect running code and variables, not logging.debug messages.

Comment: Debuggers have the advantage to give more insight into the running code and requires less back and forth in the code base while developing, logging has the advantage of being more flexible and being tool independent. Also logging is very helpful if you write a library that others should use. So I wouldn't ignore the topic completely.

Comment: They are not the same thing. If you're enabling and disabling logging.debug in such short cycles that you believe you need a command-line option for that, you're probably doing something wrong. Logging all your DEBUG entries is helpful on a pre-production step, when you believe you got everything right, but you want detailed logs in case you later realize there's something wrong. This should come from a static configuration, coupled with other development or pre-production settings, not from a command line option.